# Recursively map 3d.js graph nodes and links from nested structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, d3.js, graph

Need an elegant way to map nodes and links ready for d3.js force graph. I tried using lodash but couldn't find a way. What I need is to extract all the nested objects into a new array on a single level and also, for each object, according to its deep index, to generate a new array of links with source and target properties... for example: if an object has 2 children, I need to generate 2 links where 'source' is the parent id and the 'target' is itself id.

Here is my input structure:

```
[
   {
      "id": 0,
      "name":"Name0",
      "linkType":"PROFESSIONAL",
      "children":[
         {
            "id": 1,
            "name":"Name1",
            "linkType":"FAMILY",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id": 2,
                  "name":"Name2",
                  "linkType":"FAMILY",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name":"Name3",
                        "linkType":"FAMILY"
                     },
                     {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name":"Name4",
                        "linkType":"FAMILY"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id": 5,
                  "name":"Name5",
                  "linkType":"FAMILY"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id": 6,
            "name":"Name6",
            "linkType":"FAMILY"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
    "id": 7,
    "name":"Name7",
    "linkType":"PROFESSIONAL",
    "children":[
       {
          "id": 8,
          "name":"Name8",
          "linkType":"FAMILY",
          "children":[
             {
                "id": 9,
                "name":"Name9",
                "linkType":"FAMILY"
             },
             {
                "id": 10,
                "name":"Name10",
                "linkType":"FAMILY"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "id": 11,
          "name":"Name11",
          "linkType":"FAMILY",
          "children":[
            {
               "id": 12,
               "name":"Name12",
               "linkType":"FAMILY",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "id": 13,
                     "name":"Name13",
                     "linkType":"FAMILY"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 14,
                     "name":"Name14",
                     "linkType":"FAMILY"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id": 15,
               "name":"Name15",
               "linkType":"FAMILY"
            }
         ]
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output should be:
[image]

The result arrays should be:

```js
const nodes = [ //no matter the deep index... all the nodes will be on the same array
     { 
        "name":"Name0",
        "linkType":"PROFESSIONAL",
     },
     {
        "name":"Name7",
        "linkType":"PROFESSIONAL",
     },
     {
        "name":"Name1",
        "linkType":"FAMILY",
     }
     .
     .
     .
]

const links = [ 
    {
        id: 0, //first generated link
        source: 0 // the source node id
        target: 1 // the target node id -- node Name0 is linked with node Name1
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        source: 0
        target: 2
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        source: 1
        target: 2
    }
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use d3.hierarchy and node.descendants to get all the nodes of a given root (including that root). Then you just need to grab the relevant data and for each child create a link between that child and its parent.

That you have multiple graphs in the array adds a layer, but at the very least this should give some ideas:

```
var links = [];
var nodes = [];

nested.map(function(data) {
  d3.hierarchy(data).descendants().forEach(function(node) {
    if(node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) {
        links.push({
          target: node.data.id,
          source: child.data.id
        })
      })  

    nodes.push({
      id: node.data.id,
      name: node.data.id,
      linkType: node.data.linkType    
    })
 })
})
```

```js
var nested = [
   {
      "id": 0,
      "name":"Name0",
      "linkType":"PROFESSIONAL",
      "children":[
         {
            "id": 1,
            "name":"Name1",
            "linkType":"FAMILY",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id": 2,
                  "name":"Name2",
                  "linkType":"FAMILY",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name":"Name3",
                        "linkType":"FAMILY"
                     },
                     {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name":"Name4",
                        "linkType":"FAMILY"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id": 5,
                  "name":"Name5",
                  "linkType":"FAMILY"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id": 6,
            "name":"Name6",
            "linkType":"FAMILY"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
    "id": 7,
    "name":"Name7",
    "linkType":"PROFESSIONAL",
    "children":[
       {
          "id": 8,
          "name":"Name8",
          "linkType":"FAMILY",
          "children":[
             {
                "id": 9,
                "name":"Name9",
                "linkType":"FAMILY"
             },
             {
                "id": 10,
                "name":"Name10",
                "linkType":"FAMILY"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "id": 11,
          "name":"Name11",
          "linkType":"FAMILY",
          "children":[
            {
               "id": 12,
               "name":"Name12",
               "linkType":"FAMILY",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "id": 13,
                     "name":"Name13",
                     "linkType":"FAMILY"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 14,
                     "name":"Name14",
                     "linkType":"FAMILY"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id": 15,
               "name":"Name15",
               "linkType":"FAMILY"
            }
         ]
       }
    ]
  }
]

var links = [];
var nodes = [];

nested.map(function(data) {
  d3.hierarchy(data).descendants().forEach(function(node) {
    if(node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) {
        links.push({
          target: node.data.id,
          source: child.data.id
        })
      })  

    nodes.push({
      id: node.data.id,
      name: node.data.id,
      linkType: node.data.linkType    
    })
 })
})

console.log(links,nodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```